# How to make villagers spread around

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am planning on creating a village, but I am wondering if I can influence them to spread around a little bit more.

Currently, I have a small temporary village set up, where I have 4 houses and about 10 villagers. All the 10 villagers always cramp around in 1 single house.

How can I make it so they use up more houses? Is this intentional or a bug/glitch?

Comment: Have you build the houses or are they generated? The AI does not recognize houses sometimes.

Comment: Is that one house in the NorthWest?  http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Talk:Villager#Attracted_to_the_Northwest

Comment: @DKnight that is quite interesting, I will have to check that out. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @SaifBechan seems to be true on my game - i just tried to dig tunnels to some houses that are on other sides of the village and they are going in the tunnels but not heading out far enough to spread out in the village

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your asking is if you can influence the decisions the villagers make, and short of 'trapping' them in a place, no you cannot make them spread out as that would require you to be able to influence the AI of the villagers.

Comment: I THINK you may be able to build appropriate houses for appropriate classes. Such as the special houses with the bookshelves belong to a particular villager type, and the blacksmith house belongs to the blacksmith villager... They MAY prefer to be in the house appropriate for their type but I'm not at all sure if this works.

Comment: empirical evidence states that that is incorrect. They like to flock together, I've noticed, be it in the sheep pen or in the giant condo or in the library, so they might be attracted to each other, but not to furniture.

Answer (score 0):

Villagers always spawn in the same chunk. If you destroy the entire village and replace it with grass, they will spread out. You can then build custom houses in the area that you would like them to be in to trap the villagers.

Comment: I don't think that the OP wants to 'trap' the villagers, and besides, they can open wooden doors.

Answer (score 0):

They tend to gather at the center of the village. You can move the center of the village by expanding your village on one side. They will still tend to clump at the new center.