# Will Villagers occupy houses with half-slab roofs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built some houses for a village with elegant pitched roofs made out of half-slabs. The villagers I put there (with eggs) refused to stay, and moved elsewhere pretty quickly. Is this due to the roofs, or is there some other factor?

Comment: Can we get a picture of the house, including surrounds? The placement of blocks near the doors or the location of the house relative to other houses may matter.

Comment: probably not a problem with the house, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92760/how-to-make-villagers-spread-around for some more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roof shouldn't affect it. Look at the blocks in a 5-meter square around the door. If the light levels are equal, it won't register as a house. Also, make sure you're using a wood door, iron doors don't register as valid.

Answer (score 2):

Half slabs are a Transparent block-like stain glass and glowstone. You need a solid block above and below your door. 1 side needs a roof and the outside has to be empty or trans block to register as a house.